# Why does phpinfo() still show 7.1 after upgrading to php 7.3 on macOS Mojave (10.14.6)?

Tags: macos, mojave, apache, php

I've attempted to upgrade my version of PHP to 7.3 by running:

```
curl -s https://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh | bash -s 7.3
```

and then adding the new install to my PATH via the following line in my ~/.zshrc:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/php5/bin:$PATH"
```

I think that has worked adding it to my PATH as when I `echo $PATH` it is the first item: `/usr/local/php5/bin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/...`

In my terminal when I run `php -v` I get `PHP 7.3.8 (cli) (built: Aug 11 2019 20:50:16) ( NTS )` but when I look at a phpinfo() file in my localhost it still says PHP 7.1:

[image]

I've read this could be because the apache server could be trying to use the version of php in `/usr/bin` instead of the one in `/usr/local/php5/bin`. But I can't work out how to change it to use the newly installed PHP 7.3.

If I run `which php` it outputs `/usr/local/php5/bin/php`.

My `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf` file has the PHP 7 module loaded:

```
#LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so
LoadModule php7_module libexec/apache2/libphp7.so
```

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/360709/9058

Comment: I'm not using a brew installed version of PHP. I don't have homebrew installed.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but the answer also covers the changes required in httpd.conf

Comment: Forgive me but where does it cover the required changes? Are referring to "LoadModule php7_module /usr/local/opt/php@7.2/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so"? I don't have a /usr/local/opt. It suggests the correct way is to install Apache via HomeBrew.

Comment: You don't have /usr/local/opt, but you installed the new libphp7.so somewhere. Apache needs to know where it is.

Comment: I'll give it a shot if I can figure out where the installed 7.3 php is? I followed this guide https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/upgrade-php-on-osx/.